# Drawing a decision boundary on matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have some known parameters W=[a b], X0=[c;d] and decision boundary  W'*(x-X0) = 0. I know that if I draw a line on the points that fit on this equation, I have got a decision boundary but I could not solve it on code. How could I draw that decision line in Matlab?

Comment: Neither `w = [2;2] z = [-1;0]` or `W'(x-z)=0` are functions.... Please define more what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem by converting the equation to a format can be solved for a given x find y. Then I iterate over all possible x values and find corresponding y values. Then plot.

Comment: I had the same problem with same solution :)

Answer (score 0):

u can use matlab function for decision boundary
plotpv(i,o)
plotpc(weight,bias)

---

else you can do is, as u suggested

```
figure(1)
hold on
for i=xminLIM:xmaxLIM
    for j=yminLIM:ymaxLIM
         if(W'*([i;j]-X0) == 0)
             plot(i,j,'-r')
         end
    end
end
hold off
```